# Vertical and horizontal subspace , simple and concrete example.

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles, connections, principal-bundles

I worked a little bit on the concepts of fiber bundles, associated bundles, tangent bundle, and connections.
I studied that an ehresman connection on a principal bundle leads to the definition of a covariant derivative on an associated vector bundle. I get all the definition but in the whole reasoning there is a point where I am stuck.

It is when we define the Vertical and horizontal subspaces. In the 3 books on diff geometry I have, none provide a concrete example on how to determine the horizontal subspace. I understand that the Vertical one is defined canonically as $ker(\pi_*)$ but I have no clue how to provide one complement.

So I tried to work out a simple example but I get nowhere. I start with studying the bundle $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with the identity projection map and the group $\{1\}$. I understand this is a trivial example but I end up finding that $Vert(\mathbb{R}) = 0$. So we have no choice of horizontal subspace.

1) I would like to get an example of fiber bundle where we are faced with the choice of horizontal subspace to define a connection.

2) I would also like to have the starting fiber bundle to study that would lead me to the definition of the covariant derivative being equal to the usual euclidean directional derivative. I am trying to apply the generalization to a concrete example.

Thanks

Comment: So probably the best place for you to start is with a surface $M\subset\Bbb R^3$ with the induced Riemannian connection (so $\nabla_XY$ is the projection of the Euclidean directional derivative $D_XY$ onto the tangent plane of $M$). Now take the (oriented) orthonormal frame bundle (so we're doing the $SO(2)$ bundle). What is the horizontal subspace at $(x,\xi)$? How do you give this in terms of orthonormal moving frames?